# Is there a better way to write below program using for and if-else loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I have written the below code for my practice and it works fine, but I'm curious if the logic used in the code can be written much more efficiently or not.Any insights would be welcome:

```
public class RangeOfNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Start? ");
        int start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("End? ");
        int end = input.nextInt();
        if(start>=end){
            for (int i = start; i >=end; i--){
                if(i==end){
                    System.out.print(i);
                }else{
                    System.out.print(i+", ");
                }
            }
        }else{
            for (int i = start; i <=end; i++){
                if(i==end){
                    System.out.print(i);
                }else{
                    System.out.print(i+", ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not post this on the CodeReview part of the platform?

Comment: Is there a purpose to this code?

Comment: @Stultuske - Thanks, I will keep that in mind. Wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @Mast - There is no purpose except maybe learning, since I am a beginner and from what I heard, I need all the practice I can get. lol:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply correcting your logic, I would simply check the order to use and go for a while loop using a dynamic increment :

```
public static void iterate(int start, int end) {
    int inc = (start < end) ? 1 : -1;

    end += inc; //Allow to include the value.

    do {
        System.out.print(start);

        start += inc;

        if(start != end){
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    } while (start != end);
    System.out.println();
}
```

I have tested this with

10 -> 15

> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

15 -> 10

> 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10

Here is a complete comparison in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Lt9PgK)

Of course, I would at least use a `StringBuilder` instead of printing in the console directly.

Comment: thanks, this is way more understandable and compact than mine.if you don't mind, could you please explain what does "int inc = (start < end) ? 1 : -1;" this do in the code?

Comment: @RakeshSingh It simply define the way we need to move during the loop. `left to right = 1`, `right to left = -1`. That allow us to later simply need to add the value to `start` to move in the correct direction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Please correct my understanding if I'm wrong. This code is assigning a value to inc variable of either 1 or -1 depending on the result returned from (start<end). Is that right?

Comment: exactly @RakeshSingh. It is then added to `start`, allowing to increment if `start < end` or decrement if `start > end`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is more easy for me and tends to newer Java.

```
// Java 9 or higher version is required
class RangeOfNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Start? ");
        int start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("End? ");
        int end = input.nextInt();

       if(start < end) {
           IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
                   .peek(System.out::print)
                   .takeWhile(i -> i < end)
                   .forEach(i -> System.out.print(","));
       } else {
           IntStream.rangeClosed(end, start)
                   .map(i -> start - i + end)
                   .peek(System.out::print)
                   .takeWhile(i -> i > end)
                   .forEach(i -> System.out.print(","));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really new java, `IntStream.takeWhile` is from Java 9, you should mention the version. Stream usually means Java 8 ;)

Comment: @AxelH yes, you are right but if we'r mentioning term of "really new Java", we should refer to Java 11 :)

Comment: Fair enough ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### Joining

You may use a designated class for the joining part, for example the `StringJoiner` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)):

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    sj.add(i);
}
String result = sj.toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

---

### Stream

By using the **Stream-API** (since Java 8) you can achieve the same, but with less code in this instance:

```
String result = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

In order to get the reversed stream we need a bit of simple math:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
        .map(i -> end - i + start);
```

All together:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Start? ");
int start = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("End? ");
int end = input.nextInt();

IntStream stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end);
if (start > end) {
    stream = stream.map(i -> end - i + start);
}
String result = stream.collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: You don't need -1 in `.map(i -> end - i + start - 1);`

Comment: I was stuck with the reverse logic ... isn't there any simpler way ? Even with `Stream<Integer>` ?

Comment: @AxelH if using list is not problem or overwhelming, `descendingIterator()` can be used.